# How to use http basic auth in Rails Metal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, basic-authentication, middleware

I'm trying to implement http basic authentication in rails metal. 
Using this code:

```
class Api
  def self.call(env)
    if env["PATH_INFO"] =~ /^\/client/

    Rack::Auth::Basic.new(env) do |user, password|
      raise 'ERROR'
    end
```

But this block never executed? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest this approach instead? In your config/environments/yourenv.rb just add

```
config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Lock, "::Rack::Auth::Basic", "Staging") do |u, p|
  u == ENV['HTTPUSER'] && p == ENV['HTTPPASS']
end
```

Comment: I think he is trying to secure just one path (but this question is duplicated here many times)